# Error while sending json data with kivy front

Tags: python, http, python-requests, kivy

Hello everyone I want to transform text input of kivy application to json to send it to an API. But this error appears : AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

here is the code :

````
    def recaptcha_test_succesfull(self):
        #variables de récupérations du text input
        full_name = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.full_name.text)
        gender = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.gender.text)
        age = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.age.text)
        country = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.country.text)
        e_mail = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.e_mail.text)
        password = str(self.root.current_screen.ids.password.text)


        #variable de serializations en objets json
        data_full_name = json.dumps(str(full_name))
        data_gender = json.dumps(str(gender))
        data_age = json.dumps(int(age))
        data_country = json.dumps(str(country))
        data_e_mail = json.dumps(str(e_mail))

        #requete post/signup à l'endpoint de l'API.
        url = 'http://127.0.0.1/test_verification'
        data = {'full_name':{json.dumps(full_name)}, 'age':{json.dumps(age)}, 'country':{json.dumps(country)}, 'e_mail':{json.dumps(e_mail)}, 'gender':{json.dumps(gender)}, 'password':{json.dumps(password)}}
        response = requests.post(url, json=data)
        if (response.text) == {"Status":"Done"}:
            toast('You were successfully signed up by our services. Now, just login and enjoy with our app !')
        else:
            toast("You were not successfully signed up, please check your internet connection or your registration information and retry.")
    ```
If someone has an idea. Tell me !
````

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: @ApuCoder This error appears when I want to transform text input into json data